# How to configure Spring Actuator to run on the same port as service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring boot app that runs `https://localhost:8443`. I am trying to get Spring actuator to work on that same port. Right now, I have it working on `https://localhost:420/health` but the issue is that it works on a different port and not on port 8443. This is my config in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=69
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystores/keys.jks
server.ssl.key-password=string
management.port=420
management.ssl.enabled=true
management.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystores/keys.jks
management.ssl.key-password=string
```

When I try to change both both `server.port` and `management.port` to 8443,  I get the following error during compilation: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Management-specific SSL cannot be configured as the management server is not listening on a separate port` and `LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@194bcebf: startup date [Thu Jun 15 11:48:57 BST 2017]; root of context hierarchy`

If it is of any use, the Spring boot app consists of spring boot, jetty and apache camel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want actuator to use same port as server port, you can remove management port property. we have actuator in our project but we dont have any specific management port, we are able to access actuator end points on server port itself.

Comment: And are you using Spring web / Spring MVC?

Comment: mine is a spring boot project.. using spring-boot-starter-web.